# How can I dynamically set the attribute value of an HTML Object element in Angular 8 using a variable?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

**Browser: Chrome**

Suppose I have the following lines of code in my HTML and Typescript files:

**source.html**

```
<object class = "page" data = "www.google.com" ></object>
```

**source.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-source',
  templateUrl: './source.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./source.component.css']
})
export class SourceComponent implements OnInit {

  url:string = "www.yahoo.com";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

***The HTML file and .ts file are in the same component.***

I want to change the value of the data attribute using the **url** variable within the typescript file.

How would I go about doing this?

My HTML file doesn't recognize the **url** variable I've put in my typescript file.

Comment: The `object` element you're showing does nothing as is: https://jsfiddle.net/7efkow80/ Are you expecting it to?

Answer (score 4):

for this particular case, you need the dom sanitizer:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://www.yahoo.com");
}
```

then:

```
<object class = "page" data = "{{url}}" ></object>
```

I'm not overly familiar with object, but you might be able to get away with not using the dom sanitizer via attribute binding:

```
<object class = "page" [data]="url" ></object>
```

or

```
<object class = "page" [attr.data]="url" ></object>
```

Comment: Object refers to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object I want to insert a web page within a <div> of my main page

Comment: I know what the object tag is and what it's for. I just almost never use it. iframe's are usually the go to element for putting a page within a page

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick,

```
<object class = "page" data = "{{url}}" ></object>
```

Comment: While it does recognize the variable. It does not load the page on my end. Could it be my browser? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me :). What's the error in the console log?

Comment: ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Comment: What is your object? What type of material is that? Try appending http:// to the beginning of the url.

Comment: I've tried adding http:// to the beginning to google.com           That doesn't work either

Comment: Yeah.. so object is overly vague. What is object? Why are you using object as the tag? What is an Object tag? I think the Object tag is the underlying problem to understand ATM (At The Moment)......... I see that you have angular-material as meta.

Comment: Object refers to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object I want to insert a web page within a <div> of my main page

Comment: Why not just use an iframe?